# When the time expires, the function starts again from the beginning

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame as pg
pg.init()

def fixTime():
    totalTime = 4
    return totalTime

while 1:
    flowTime = int(pg.time.get_ticks()/1000)
    elapsed_time = (fixTime() - flowTime)

    if elapsed_time <=0:
        fixTime()
    else:
        print(elapsed_time)
```

When the current ends, 1 is repeated, but I want to make a function that returns the time to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks):

> Return the number of milliseconds since `pygame.init()` was called.

You can just subtract 2 time values:

```py
def get_elapsed_time(from_time = 0):
    to_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    return to_time - from_time

start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks():
while run:

    elapsed = get_elapsed_time(start_time)
    # [...]
```

[`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) returns the time in milliseconds. If you want the time in seconds you must divide by 1000. e.g.: `return (to_time - from_time) / 1000`